# MEAN stack: How to get the _id of a posted item inside a controller?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I'm using the MEAN stack to build a an application where users can create new posts (my first MEAN application attempt). Whenever a user makes a new post and it appears on the page I'd like it to play a short CSS animation to indicate its position to the user. I've been thinking of adding a small CSS animation class to the `div` the new post appears in, but this is where I've ran into problems.

Each post is in its own `div` whose id is the post's `_id`.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: order">

    <div id="{{post._id}}">  // this is where I'd like to add the animation class 
       {{post.text}}    
    </div> 

</div>
```

I have a factory where the create method for a new post looks like this:

```
var o = {posts: []};

o.create = function(post) {
  return $http.post('/posts', post, {
  }).then(function(response){
    o.posts.push(response.data);
    // return response.data;
  });
};
```

In order for me to be able to add the CSS animation class to the new post I need to know its `_id`, since it's also its `div`'s id. I know I'm able to get the new post's `_id` by returning the now commented `response.data` from the factory to my controller by using the following:

```
posts.create(newPost).then(function(successResponse) { // posts.create is the factory method above    
  console.log(successResponse._id);   // This works fine

  var id = '#' + successResponse._id; 
  $(id).addClass('flashNew');         // This does not work
});
```

But I can't seem to access the `div` from inside `then()`. I'm assuming the correct `div`does not yet exist at this point...?

I also don't know how I could access the `successResponse._id` from outside of the `then()`.

What should I do? Is this even a good approach to this sort of a thing?

Comment: you seem to have an `id` to work from as in `<div id="{{post._id}}"> ` why are you doing all the other stuff, seems kinda roundabout?

Comment: @Jax I'm a noob. :) So, you're suggest getting the id from the $scope array after it updates there? Since I don't know before hand what the post's _id will be I'm not sure what would be the best way to grab the id from the array. Could it e.g. be possible that choosing the newest post in the array would return a post another user has posted at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are adding the class before the `<div>` gets rendered. I have an example where I add a `$timeout` and it works fine. just take a look at the example code below:

```js
var app = angular.module('ngApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
  'use strict';

  $scope.posts = [{
    text: 'blah',
    _id: 1
  }, {
    text: 'balls',
    _id: 2
  }];
  var i = 3
  $scope.addPost = function() {
    i = i + 1
    var post = {
      text: 'post with id ' + i,
      _id: i
    };

    $scope.posts.push(post);
    $timeout(function() {
      var id = '#' + post._id;
      var myElement = $(id);

      $(myElement).addClass('flashPost');

    }, 1);

  }
}]);
```

```css
.flashPost {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ngApp">

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <button type='button' ng-click='addPost()'>Add Post</button>
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts">

      <div id="{{post._id}}">{{post.text}} <br/> Div's id = {{post._id}}
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Bear in mind I am simulating the server call to create a new `post`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!